# Как создать логический тип поля?

Tags: access

Делаю отдельную таблицу, заполняю ее полями одно М другое Ж, при выборе пишется

> the value you entered does not match yes/no data type in this column

Comment: Можно подробнее? По идее стоит сделать два поля, одно - "пол указан" (истина/ложь), второе - "мужчина" (истина/ложь). Ну а тип поля задается в конструкторе, если вы это имеете в виду. Откройте таблицу и выберите в меню Главная->Режим->Конструктор.

Comment: я так и делал, но ни в какую

Answer (score 1):

М.б. стоит использовать для поля мастер подстановки и выбрать из "фиксированного набора значений" (М, Ж)?